# How do I setup an unsecured HTTP only docker-registry

Tags: docker-registry

`docker run -d -p 5000 -v /tmp/registry:/tmp/registry --name="docker-registry" registry`

`docker push <docker-registry-ip>:5000/ubuntu`

Resulting in the error:

`FATA[0000] Error: v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get http://<docker-registry-ip>:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp <docker-registry-ip>:5000: connection refused`

I have already added below to `/etc/default/docker` and restarted docker service
`DOCKER_OPTS="$DOCKER_OPTS --insecure-registry=<docker-registry-ip>:5000"`

Answer (score 0):

You did not bind the port on the host. When you only mention -p 5000, it is for the container port, and binds to a random port on the host. You will need to run:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 -v /tmp/registry:/tmp/registry --name="docker-registry" registry
```

Also don't forget to tag the image first before you push it:

```
docker tag Ubuntu <docker-registry-ip>:5000/ubuntu
```